# Showing isomorphism between subgroup of symmetric group and dihedral group.

Tags: group-theory

I have to show that subgroup of symmetric group $S_4$ generated by $(12)$ and $(13)(24)$ is isomorphic to dihedral group $D_4$. I calculated that group generated by $(12)$ and $(13)(24)$ is 
$$\langle (12),(13)(24)\rangle = \{ (1), (12),(13)(24), (1324), (12)(34), (34), (14)(23), (1423)\}$$
I know that members of $D_4$ is
$$
D_4 = \{ (1), (13), (24), (1234), (13)(24), (1432), (12)(34), (14)(23)\}
$$
I am little confused. What map (based on) do I need to define in order to show that isomorphism exists between them?

Comment: Try numbering the four vertices of a square $1,2,3,4$ in order. Then think about the elements of $D_4$ permute the indices.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I see thanks :) Perhaps using $(23)$ as a map should do??