# Showing isomorphism between Klein group and subgroup of $D_4$

Tags: group-theory

I am given that Klein four group as 
$$K = \{ (1), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$$
and the subgroup of $D_4$ generated by $\langle (13),(1234)^2 \rangle $. I need to show that there is isomorphism between these two. I know 
$$\langle (13),(1234)^2 \rangle = \{ (1), (13), (13)(24), (24)\}$$
What map should I take which shows isomorphism (if exists) between these two?

Comment: In the case of $V_4$, this is excessively easy: _Any_ bijective map that takes the identity to the identity will turn out to be an isomorphism!

Comment: @HenningMakholm could you please give me an example of such map?

Comment: I could, but you can do it just as well yourself. Just throw dice or whatever to decide which of the non-identity elements map to which -- it will work alright.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah!! Perhaps It might work [here as well](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738147/showing-isomorphism-between-subgroup-of-symmetric-group-and-dihedral-group)